# How do you save the contents of an NSCollectionView?

Tags: cocoa, save, nscollectionview

I have an nscollectionview which holds collectionitems which the user can add/delete. Each collectionitem holds a textview and an imageview. I have managed so save strings to files using NSSavePanel but how would I get the contents of the textview and imageview so I can save them to an array by iterating through the array holding the collectionitems?

or

Is there a better way to save the contents of the collectionitem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Only you can decide how best to persist your application's data, but you need to understand the difference between your view (the collection view and its items' views) and your model (the things represented by the views, arranged and managed by the controller).

So: Since your collection view is showing an array of things, doesn't it make sense to save that array of things? Make sure the things in the array are [serializable](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/serializing.html) then use [NSArray's -writeToURL:atomically:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) method to write the array and its serializable content out to a file.

Just remember, you're not saving your view, you're saving the data represented by the view (and mediated/controlled/managed by the controller layer). See t[he Model-View-Controller design pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html) for more information.